# Submitting a URL into a Form without "http://", with "www.", or with neither

Tags: php, mysql

(EDITED)

Hello,

In the form below, the field for `<div class="urlfield"><input name="url" type="url" id="url" maxlength="500"></div>` fine when a URL is submitted that has a "http://" at the beginning of it.

However, it doesn't work if a URL is submitted with only a "www." in front of it, or with neither a "http://" nor a "www."

How can I make it work if the submitted URL has any or none of the following at the beginning of it:

```
http://

www.

http://www.
```

Thanks in advance,

John

Form:

```
echo '<div class="submittitle">Submit an item.</div>';  

echo '<form action="http://www...com/.../submit2.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" value="'.$_SESSION['loginid'].'" name="uid">  

 <div class="submissiontitle"><label for="title">Story Title:</label></div> 
    <div class="submissionfield"><input name="title" type="title" id="title" maxlength="1000"></div>  

 <div class="urltitle"><label for="url">Link:</label></div> 
    <div class="urlfield"><input name="url" type="url" id="url" maxlength="500"></div>

    <div class="submissionbutton"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
</form>
';
```

submit2.php:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){header('Location: http://www...com/.../submit2.php');}

require_once "header.php";


if (isLoggedIn() == true)
{

$remove_array = array('http://www.', 'http://', 'https://', 'https://www.', 'www.');
$cleanurl = str_replace($remove_array, "", $_POST['url']);
$cleanurl = strtolower($cleanurl);
$cleanurl = preg_replace('/\/$/','',$cleanurl);
$cleanurl = stripslashes($cleanurl);

$title = $_POST['title'];
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
$title = stripslashes($title);

$cleanurl = mysql_real_escape_string($cleanurl);

$site1 = 'http://' . $cleanurl;

$displayurl = parse_url($site1, PHP_URL_HOST);

function isURL($url1 = NULL) {
        if($url1==NULL) return false;

        $protocol = '(http://|https://)';
        $allowed = '[-a-z0-9]{1,63}';

        $regex = "^". $protocol . // must include the protocol
                         '(' . $allowed . '\.)'. // 1 or several sub domains with a max of 63 chars
                         '[a-z]' . '{2,6}'; // followed by a TLD
        if(eregi($regex, $url1)==true) return true;
        else return false;
}



if(isURL($site1)==true)
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO submission VALUES (NULL, '$uid', '$title', '$cleanurl', '$displayurl', NULL)");
else
 echo "<p class=\"topicu\">Not a valid URL.</p>\n";

} else {
    show_loginform();
}

if (!isLoggedIn())
{
    if (isset($_POST['cmdlogin']))
    {
        if (checkLogin($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))
        {
            show_userbox();
        } else
        {
            echo "Incorrect Login information !";
            show_loginform();
        }
    } else
    {
        show_loginform();
    }

} else
{
    show_userbox();
}

require_once "footer.php";

?>
```

Comment: But it looks like you strip the http:// or www. or whatever off the url with $remove_array,and then you add http:// back on to create $site1, so how can there be a difference between initially having it or not?

Comment: Check my edited comment. It may be that you just need to `trim()` the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine to me, but Echo the value of the passed url at several points to see where the code is failing.

Edit try making `$cleanurl = mysql_real_escape_string($cleanurl);`

`$cleanurl = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($cleanurl));`

Comment: I just tested the exact script you have (without the mysql_real_escape_string) and it works for all test urls.

Comment: Stick `echo '-'.$site1.'-';` before the if statement so you can see what value it is sending and make sure there is no whitespaces. The script works for me.

Comment: The weird thing is, I can't even get to submit2.php if I try to enter a URL with http://... the submit button just doesn't do anything.

Comment: You are using an HTML5 form, does your browser support it? Try replacing `type="url"` with `type="text"`.

Comment: I'm using Chrome... but I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Change it to type="text" seems to have solved the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without the protocol (`http://`), a browser should consider the url relative.

Get rid of the host (www...com) part, and start from the following slash to use the url relative to the domain's document root.

Alternatively, use an url relative to the url of the page where the form resides (could be `"../../something/else/submit.php"` for example.

To build a relative url dynamically without resorting to the domain root, you may find the predefined variable `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` useful (the exact contents of which may vary depending on which web server is in question).

Comment: I may not have been clear enough before I edited my question, but I a, asking about the URL the user enters into <div class="urlfield"><input name="url" type="url" id="url" maxlength="500"></div> on the form.